# Nifi ExecuteSQL failed to process session due to createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-nifi, hstore

I'm working with Nifi and I would like to transfer data from a postgresql's table to Json files.

I have a table in postgresql database with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."users" (
 "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
 "email" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
 "settings" "public"."hstore" NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::hstore,
 "credited_at" timestamp(6)
);

CREATE INDEX "index_users_on_settings" ON "public"."users" USING gist (
 "settings" "public"."gist_hstore_ops"
);

ALTER TABLE "public"."users" ADD CONSTRAINT "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");
```

I tried to get data from this `user` table to `json` files by **Nifi** with data flow.

Main Nifi flow: 
[image]
Fetch Data from user table and move to Nifi RGP:
[image]
Get data and run ExecuteSQL:
[image]
Error when start ExecuteSQL:
[image]

And I got the error with Avro's schema

> ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041] ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041] failed to process session due to createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot be converted to Avro type; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot be converted to Avro type

I tried to search a solution on google but there aren't any way to fix this. 
Could you please help me? 
Thank you.

This is my stacktrace from nifi-app.log

> 2018-05-03 04:54:43,418 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6]
>   o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041]
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041] failed to process
>   session due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema:
>   Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot
>   be converted to Avro type; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1
>   sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown SQL
>   type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot be
>   converted to Avro type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column:
>   settings) cannot be converted to Avro type    at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.createSchema(JdbcCommon.java:621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.lambda$onTrigger$1(ExecuteSQL.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.onTrigger(ExecuteSQL.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2018-05-03 04:54:43,418 WARN
>   [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask
>   Administratively Yielding
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041] due to uncaught
>   Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown
>   SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot be
>   converted to Avro type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column:
>   settings) cannot be converted to Avro type    at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.createSchema(JdbcCommon.java:621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.lambda$onTrigger$1(ExecuteSQL.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.onTrigger(ExecuteSQL.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2018-05-03 04:54:43,501 INFO
>   [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService
>   Saved flow controller
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@65ee54e8 // Another save
>   pending = false 2018-05-03 04:54:44,423 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process
>   Thread-9] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041]
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041] failed to process
>   session due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema:
>   Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot
>   be converted to Avro type; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1
>   sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown SQL
>   type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot be
>   converted to Avro type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column:
>   settings) cannot be converted to Avro type    at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.createSchema(JdbcCommon.java:621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.lambda$onTrigger$1(ExecuteSQL.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.onTrigger(ExecuteSQL.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2018-05-03 04:54:44,423 WARN
>   [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask
>   Administratively Yielding
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041] due to uncaught
>   Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown
>   SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot be
>   converted to Avro type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column:
>   settings) cannot be converted to Avro type    at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.createSchema(JdbcCommon.java:621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.lambda$onTrigger$1(ExecuteSQL.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.onTrigger(ExecuteSQL.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2018-05-03 04:54:45,427
>   ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9]
>   o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041]
>   ExecuteSQL[id=1f22e067-0163-1000-ffff-ffff9c047041] failed to process
>   session due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema:
>   Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot
>   be converted to Avro type; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1
>   sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown SQL
>   type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column: settings) cannot be
>   converted to Avro type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / hstore (table: users, column:
>   settings) cannot be converted to Avro type    at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.createSchema(JdbcCommon.java:621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.lambda$onTrigger$1(ExecuteSQL.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2621)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.onTrigger(ExecuteSQL.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Looks like the `settings` column is of a non-standard type. Can you share the full stacktrace from `nifi-app.log`?

Comment: hi @SivaprasannaSethuraman, yes, the problem come frome `settings` column, but I don't know how to fix it. I updated stacktrace on my post.

Comment: You should give the [NiFi mailing list](https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html) a try as well if you don't get a response here. If you do get an answer remember to share it here as well and mark it as answered :-)

Comment: hi @timss I asked them, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in NiFi 1.9.0+ (see [NIFI-5845](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5845) for more details)